# Force Mongoose default

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I have a Mongoose schema with a field like `created`, and I want `created` to be the current timestamp *even if a value is passed to the constructor*, how do I force the default? Do I need to use middleware? Here's what I want to do:

```js
const fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    forceDefault: true,
  }
});

const Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);

const foo = new Foo({created: new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00'));
```

In the above example, the goal is to have `foo.created` be the current date even though that's not what was passed to the constructor. I was thinking of using a setter or middleware, but this seems a bit hacky for something so simple.

Comment: @turivishal the created field was an example; my use case has to do with setting an initial uses field to 0 upon document creation.

Comment: Okay so you can use pre middleware.